# Product of Fourier integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I am interested in solving the following integral:

\begin{equation}
I =\int dx_{3}\psi^{\star}(x_{3})\int dx_{1}\psi(x_{1})\int dq_{1}X(q_{1})e^{iq_{1}(x_{3}-x_{1})}\int dx_{2}\psi(x_{2})\int dq_{2}X(q_{2})e^{iq_{2}(x_{3}-x_{2})}\int dk\, X^{\star}(k)\, X^{\star}(q_{1}+q_{2}-k)\, e^{ik(x-x_{3})}
\end{equation}

Background info

---

In general, looking at an integral of the form $\int dx^{\prime}\psi(x^{\prime})\int dk\,f(k)\,e^{ik(x-x^{\prime})}$, for a generic function $f(k)$, we can proceed by expanding our generic function in a Taylor Series around $k=0$, and get:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\int dx^{\prime}\psi(x^{\prime})\int dkk^{n}e^{ik(x-x^{\prime})}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\left(-i\right)^{n}\int dx^{\prime}\psi(x^{\prime})\partial_{x}^{n}\delta(x-x^{\prime})
\end{equation}

where we have used the well-known relation $\int dkk{}^{n}e^{ik(x-x^{\prime})}=\left(-i\right)^{n}\partial_{x}^{n}\delta(x-x^{\prime})$.

Moving the derivative operator to act on $\psi$ (integration by parts), we finally obtain

\begin{equation}
\int dx^{\prime}\psi(x^{\prime})\int dkf(k)e^{ik(x-x^{\prime})}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}(i\partial_{x})^{n}\psi(x)=f(i\partial_{x})\psi(x)
\end{equation}

---

Now coming back to the original integral, instead of $f$ we have the functions $X$, but the nesting of the integrals makes it difficult to use the above method. The goal is to express the result as a differential operator (or sum of such operators) acting on the functions $\psi$. Perhaps a change of variables would help?

Comment: This question is very difficult to understand. It is not clear to me what the $\psi$, the capital $X$, or the star means (for example, if these are specific functions, or just placeholders). Also, it seems that you want to evaluate a product of integrals. If so, why not ask specific questions for the ones you have having trouble with, instead of the entire product?

Comment: @Potato, I appologise about the confusion, the $\psi$ and $X$ are just complex functions, and the star means complex conjugate. And the product is not separable, that is the problem. I would like to simplify it as in the example shown in 'background info'.